# ServiceStack - Saving AutoQuery Requests

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

Regarding ServiceStack's AutoQuery, I would like to enable the user to

1. [Save] AutoQuery requests (& provide a name for the Request) - see screenshot
2. view all saved request & re-run a given request.

[image]

How do I implement this using ServiceStack?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added support for saved queries in [AutoQuery Viewer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin) in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin/commit/b0b3785e2b71e0a9c20d1d63f912f4f8851f4fb4) where you can save queries under each AutoQuery Service by clicking the **save icon**. The saved query will be listed with the name provided and displayed to the right of the save icon, e.g:

[image]

This feature is available from v4.0.63 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).